# WSO2 Jaggery - how to parse a number into an integer

Tags: javascript, wso2, jaggery-js

In this simple jaggery code

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

print(i);

}
```

Output was like

```
0.0

1.0
```

....

I need to parse these outputs into integer. I tried `parseInt(i)` method but it also gave the same result. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I think what you got is correct. JavaScript has the Number type only for numerical values. Usually you shouldn't print numbers directly. Ideally a number should be formatted before printing. i.e. You should print only after you have a string representation of the number. I'm not providing an answer as I don't have much experience with Jaggery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Jaggery expert, but i have tried your code Try It tool which can be found in [Jaggery Website](http://jaggeryjs.org/) and it gave me expected result.

The sample code i have tried is,

```
<html> 
  <body> 
    <h1> 
      <% 
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
          print(i "\n");
        } 
      %> 
    </h1> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Which gave me output,

```
0123456789
```

HTH,

DarRay